# Kafka Spark Streaming : Broker may not be available [Docker]

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm new to docker. I'm trying to run a spark streaming application using docker.

I have kafka and spark streaming application running separately in 2 containers.

My kafka service is up and running fine. I tested with $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh and $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh. I'm able to receive messages.

But when I'm running my spark streaming application, it's showing:

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=consumer-spark] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

So, I'm not able to consume messages.

**kafka : docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**Spark Streaming code:**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Twitter Ingest Data")
    sparkConf.setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    val kafkaTopics = "sentiment"
    val kafkaBroker = "kafka:9092"

    val topics : Set[String] = kafkaTopics.split(",").map(_.trim).toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String,Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> kafkaBroker,
              "group.id" -> "consumer-spark",
              "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
              "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer]
    )

    logger.info("Connecting to broker...")
    logger.info(s"kafkaParams: $kafkaParams")

    val tweetStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Docker, I wouldn't recommend having Kafka or Spark being the first things you're trying it with. Besides, seems like you just copied the wurstmeister example one without reading the README about configuring it... (which I can tell because you don't need the `build: .` property because that container already exists on DockerHub)

Basically, Kafka is only available **within** your Docker network via this configuration

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

You will need to edit this to have the port forwarding work properly from outside of Docker Compose's default network, or you must run your Spark code within a container as well.

If the Spark code is not in a container, then pointing it at `kafka:9092` won't work at all

Ref. [Kafka listeners explained](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)

And lots of [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka+docker?sort=votes&pageSize=15) with similar problems (the issue is not just Spark related)

Comment: As I already mentioned in the beginning of my post, I'm running my spark-streaming application in another container. My app is still not able to establish connection to the broker. Let me know if I missed anything in the configuration.

Comment: Your Spark container needs to be started from the same Docker-Compose file as Kafka, then, or you must add a `--net` parameter onto the `docker run` command using the same network as the Kafka container